# error '(' expected but identifier found in Scala

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I'm using Scala Worksheet in IntelliJ IDEA and sometimes I get this kind of error. For example this is my code:

```
def silnia(n:Int):Int=
  if n==0 then 1
  else if n>0 then n*silnia(n-1)
  else throw new Exception(s"negative number: $n")
```

It compiled normally before both in IntelliJ and Terminal and I got the expected result:

```
def silnia(n: Int): Int
```

but now it doesn't and instead I get this error `'(' expected but identifier found`. I don't think the problem is in the code but I could be wrong. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your version of Scala?

Comment: My version of Scala is Scala 3.0.2

Comment: Support of Scala 3 is still not perfect in IntelliJ

Comment: > "but now it doesn't [compile]": 
Is the code in your question the **exact** code you are getting the compilation error for?

Comment: @tjheslin1 yes. I already found the cause of my problem. I hadn't picked Scala 3 in IntelliJ